# Multiple RecycleView OnClickListener not triggered

Tags: android

I have two RecycleView in one fragment. I tried to implement setOnClickListener() at both RecycleView. Each RecycleView OnClickListener will run different function. But when i click the item, it's not triggered at at all. Below is my code at fragment

```
    public class NewsFragment extends BaseFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, NewsAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    NewsAdapter adapterInfonitas;
    NewsAdapter adapterIndoChina;
    @BindView(R.id.newsLocation)
    Spinner newsLocation;
    @BindView(R.id.newsInfonitas)
    RecyclerView newsInfonitas;
    @BindView(R.id.newsIndoChina)
    RecyclerView newsIndoChina;
    @BindView(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout)
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    Unbinder unbinder;

    CityAdapter adapterCity;

    List<City> listCity = new ArrayList<City>();

    public NewsFragment() {
    }

    public static NewsFragment newInstance() {
        return new NewsFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        setUp();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(NewsFragment.this);
        return view;
    }

    private void setUp() {

        adapterCity = new CityAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listCity);
        newsLocation.setAdapter(adapterCity);
        newsLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                City city = adapterCity.getItem(position);
                loadNewsIndochina(city.getSlug());
                loadNewsInfonitas(city.getSlug());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        adapterInfonitas = new NewsAdapter(getContext(), this);
        newsInfonitas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        newsInfonitas.setAdapter(adapterInfonitas);
        newsInfonitas.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        newsInfonitas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "AAAAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// not trigger when click item
            }
        });

        adapterIndoChina = new NewsAdapter(getContext(), this);
        newsIndoChina.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        newsIndoChina.setAdapter(adapterIndoChina);
        newsIndoChina.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        newsInfonitas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "BBBB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// not trigger when click item
            }
        });

        loadData();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        listCity.add(new City("All city", "0"));
        loadCity();
        loadNewsIndochina("0");
        loadNewsInfonitas("0");
    }

    private void loadCity() {
        client.getListNewsCity()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<List<City>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                        compositeDisposable.add(d);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<List<City>> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            listCity.addAll(response.body());
                            adapterCity.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private void loadNewsInfonitas(String city) {
        if (city != "0") {
            client.getListNewsInfonitasByCity(city)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<List<NewsItem>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
//                        compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<List<NewsItem>> response) {
                            if (response.code() == 401) {
                                logOut();
                            } else if (response.code() == 200) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    List<NewsItem> listNewsInfonitas = new ArrayList<NewsItem>(response.body().subList(response.body().size() - 3, response.body().size()));
                                    adapterInfonitas.updateItems(listNewsInfonitas);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.failed_get_news, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
//                        compositeDisposable.clear();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                            if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            responseError(e);
//                        compositeDisposable.clear();
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            client.getListNewsInfonitas()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<List<NewsItem>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
//                        compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Response<List<NewsItem>> response) {
                            if (response.code() == 401) {
                                logOut();
                            } else if (response.code() == 200) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    List<NewsItem> listNewsInfonitas = new ArrayList<NewsItem>(response.body().subList(response.body().size() - 3, response.body().size()));
                                    adapterInfonitas.updateItems(listNewsInfonitas);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.failed_get_news, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
//                        compositeDisposable.clear();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                            if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            responseError(e);
//                        compositeDisposable.clear();
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    private void loadNewsIndochina(String city) {
        if (city != "0") {
            client.getListNewsIndochinaByCity(city)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<List<NewsItem>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
//                        compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Response<List<NewsItem>> response) {
                            if (response.code() == 401) {
                                logOut();
                            } else if (response.code() == 200) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    List<NewsItem> listNewsIndoChina = new ArrayList<NewsItem>(response.body().subList(response.body().size() - 3, response.body().size()));
                                    adapterIndoChina.updateItems(listNewsIndoChina);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.failed_get_news, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
//                        compositeDisposable.clear();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }
                    });
        } else {
            client.getListNewsIndochina()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<List<NewsItem>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
//                        compositeDisposable.add(d);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Response<List<NewsItem>> response) {
                            if (response.code() == 401) {
                                logOut();
                            } else if (response.code() == 200) {
                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    List<NewsItem> listNewsIndoChina = new ArrayList<NewsItem>(response.body().subList(response.body().size() - 3, response.body().size()));
                                    adapterIndoChina.updateItems(listNewsIndoChina);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.failed_get_news, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
//                        compositeDisposable.clear();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CCCCCC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
//        if (swipeRefreshLayout != null) swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
//        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NewsDetailActivity.class);
//        intent.putExtra("news_id", adapter.getNewsId(position));
//        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and below is my NewsAdapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NewsItem> listNews = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context ctx;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public NewsAdapter(Context ctx, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_news, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(listNews.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listNews.size();
    }

    public String getNewsId(int position) {
        return listNews.get(position).getId();
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.txtTitleNews)
        TextView txtTitleNews;
        @BindView(R.id.imgBackgroundNews)
        ImageView imgBackgroundNews;
        @BindView(R.id.lblDateNews)
        TextView lblDateNews;
        @BindView(R.id.txtSubTitleNews)
        TextView txtSubTitleNews;
        String newsId;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(NewsItem item) {
            newsId = item.getId();
            txtTitleNews.setText(item.getTitle());
            txtSubTitleNews.setText(item.getSubtitle());
            lblDateNews.setText(item.getDate());
            if (!item.getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("No Thumbnail Available")) {
                Glide.with(ctx).load(item.getImage()).fitCenter().into(imgBackgroundNews);
            }
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.newsRL)
        public void onViewClicked() {
            listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public void updateItems(final List<NewsItem> newItems) {
        final List<NewsItem> oldItems = new ArrayList<>(this.listNews);
        this.listNews.clear();
        if (newItems != null) {
            this.listNews.addAll(newItems);
        }
        DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return oldItems.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return listNews.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return oldItems.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newItems.get(newItemPosition));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return oldItems.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newItems.get(newItemPosition));
            }

        }).dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }
}
```

Can someone point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Setting an `OnClickListener` directly on a `RecyclerView` won't do anything. Item clicks are handled in your `NewsAdapter`, and you've passed the `Fragment` as the listener in the constructor calls. Your clicks should be firing its `onItemClick()` method. Move a `Toast` there to check.

Comment: @MikeM. i already implement onItemClick() as u mention, and also did test the Toast. But still not triggered. I already update my fragment code, do u mind to see again

Comment: You forgot to call `show()` on that `Toast`. I guess you forgot it on the others, too, but I missed it.

Comment: OMG!! what a fool im. Thanks men, its worked now. Please post your answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Meh, just a minor oversight. :-) If you wanna call it a freebie, you can just delete this. Otherwise, feel free to post your own answer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Forget to add `show()` to my Toast. Thanks [Mike M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) insight.